# Create a file if it does not exist and the open it using python

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.6

I am trying to write a program that creates a file (if it doesn't exists yet) and then writes a text in it. My code looks like

```
            with open(("test_program/files/{}.txt").format("houses"), 'w+') as f:
                w = csv.writer(f)
                w.writerow([('This is the file with houses')])
```

But I get the error

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'test_program/files/houses.txt'
```

I am using python 3.6

Comment: Do those folders exist yet? Code works fine, if so

Comment: `open` can create files, but **not** directories. In this case, `test_program` and/or `files` does not exist.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed that path to the file was wrong.